# Library function returns raw pointer and I want to use smart pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have this situation where the library I use has many functions that return raw pointers to objects, how could I now use boost smart pointers in my program using this library and using smart pointers?

The library is xerces-C++ and an example is getting the document iterator:

```
boost::shared_ptr<DOMNodeIterator> itera = document->createNodeIterator(rootelement, DOMNodeFilter::SHOW_ALL, NULL, true);
```

The `createNodeIterator` function returns a pointer to a `DOMNodeIterator` object, this is a raw pointer and therefore cannot be cast just like that to a `boost::shared_ptr`...  How would I best deal with this?  Use raw pointers instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the library provides a way of releasing those **raw** pointers ?

If so, you can just "create" a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter, specifying the "free function" provided by the library.

Example:

If you have the two functions:

```
Foo* createFoo();
void freeFoo(Foo* foo);
```

You can create a `shared_ptr` that way:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo(createFoo(), freeFoo);
```

If the **raw** pointer is not meant to be released, you can instead provide a "null-deleter" that does nothing when the reference counter reaches 0.

Comment: @Tony: Can you give me the code that releases a raw pointer ? I could then show you an example solution.

Comment: @ereOn: You saying you want the implementation of the DOMNodeIterator::release function?

Comment: @Tony: Dunno. Just a sample code on how you allocate then release such a raw pointer. I never used Xerces.

Comment: @ereOn why will you need a smart pointer if no cleanup is necessary?

Comment: @ruslik: For consistency's sake. Sometimes, you design an API which returns smart pointers. Depending on several things, you might either want to return a "owned" smart pointer or a "null deleter" one. The caller of your API don't have to care about deallocation and uses the same type everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `boost::shared_ptr<DOMNodeIterator> itera = document->createNodeIterator(rootelement, DOMNodeFilter::SHOW_ALL, NULL, true);` to `boost::shared_ptr<DOMNodeIterator> itera( document->createNodeIterator(rootelement, DOMNodeFilter::SHOW_ALL, NULL, true));` and it should compile fine.

Comment: And what if the library does not use `new` to allocate the pointer ? The `shared_ptr` will then use `delete` when something else was expected, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I assumed that since OP wanted to use a `shared_ptr` the intention is to automatically `delete` the object.

Comment: @ereOn, @Naveen: That concrete library requires user code to call a custom function to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the object locally use boost::scoped_ptr instead of boost:shared_ptr as this is very dangerous if you pass as a parameter to some other function.  If you are dealing with shared_ptr, you have think about object reference count as well.

If you use Scoped_ptr, it automatically deletes when scope of the object ends.

Class Foo
boost::scoped_ptr objfoo(new Foo());

Comment: The problem (unspecified in the question) is that the concrete library requires the user to call a custom function to release the memory. That requirement does not fit well with using `scope_ptr`